# IE9 and the <audio> tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

I have a 100% valid html5 document, on every other browser on every OS, there are no problems, but on IE9, I always just get the black rectangle with a red cross on it instead of audio player. I thought that it might be conflicting somehow with the activeX.

Thanks.

```
<audio controls="controls">
        <source src="/files/NRUPPLYSNINGEN_XTRA.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="/files/NRUPPLYSNINGEN_XTRA.wav" type="audio/wav">
        <source src="/files/NRUPPLYSNINGEN_XTRA.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question, but could it be that the path to the audio files are not correct?
Chrome renders the audio player nicely even if the audio files cannot be found. However, IE9 does not seem to do that.

If I replace the audio file with a working one then the cross goes away and everything works fine.

```
<audio controls="controls">
        <source src="http://open.is/jQueryMusicPlayer/betty.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>​
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/PFTaN/